# Cumulative Monthly YTD Based on Threshold

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.5, threshold

I am trying to create a cumulative monthly ytd calculation where based on a threshold a 'player' is only counted towards the numerator & denominator once (as soon as they have a recorded score) and can move into the "met threshold" group and then even if they then later have a score that doesn't meet the threshold, they remain in the group.

I'm not sure what to call this model, but would love any ideas on implementation or around what this type of logic is considered so that I can research on my own.

Here is what an example input dataframe would be:

```
 Player     Month   Score   Qualified?
 A          January     3   N
 A          February    4   Y
 A          March       5   Y
 A          April       5   Y
 B          January     4   Y
 B          February    3   N
 C          March       5   Y
 D          February    3   N
 D          March       4   Y
 D          April       3   N
 E          April       1   N
```

And the output: (the player names are only there to help with tracking the logic)

```
 Month      Qualified Players         Players
 January    1 (B)                      2 (A, B)
 February   2 (A, B)                   3 (A, B, D)
 March      4 (A, B, C, D)             4 (A, B, C, D)
 April      4 (A, B, C, D)             5 (A, B, C, D, E)
```

Update:
Above is the model at it's simplest. At a deeper level, I want to have multiple threshold groups where, similarly, a player can move up a threshold group but can never move down. Example:

Threshold groups = Low(1-2), Medium(3-4), High(5)

Input df(same as above):

```
 Player     Month   Score   Qualified?
 A          January     3   N
 A          February    4   Y
 A          March       5   Y
 A          April       5   Y
 B          January     4   Y
 B          February    3   N
 C          March       5   Y
 D          February    3   N
 D          March       4   Y
 D          April       3   N
 E          April       1   N
```

Output df:

```
 Month  Threshold Group     Player Count
 1      Low                 0
 1      Medium              2 (A, B)
 1      High                0
 2      Low                 0
 2      Medium              3 (A, B, D)
 2      High                0
 3      Low                 0
 3      Medium              2 (B, D)
 3      High                2 (A, C)
 4      Low                 1 (E)
 4      Medium              2 (B, D)
 4      High                2 (A, C)
```

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'player':list('AAAABBCDDDE'), 'month':[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,2,3,4,4], 'score':[3,4,5,5,4,3,5,3,4,3,1]})
>>> df

    month player  score
0       1      A      3
1       2      A      4
2       3      A      5
3       4      A      5
4       1      B      4
5       2      B      3
6       3      C      5
7       2      D      3
8       3      D      4
9       4      D      3
10      4      E      1

>>> res = df.groupby('month')
            .apply(func=lambda x: ''.join(x.player.values))
            .rename('active')
            .to_frame()

>>> res['qualified'] = df.groupby('month')
                         .apply(func=lambda x: ''.join(x[x.score>=4].player.values))

>>> res

      active qualified
month                 
1         AB         B
2        ABD         A
3        ACD       ACD
4        ADE         A

>>> res.cumsum().applymap(lambda x: np.unique(list(x)))

                active     qualified
month                               
1               [A, B]           [B]
2            [A, B, D]        [A, B]
3         [A, B, C, D]  [A, B, C, D]
4      [A, B, C, D, E]  [A, B, C, D]
```

honestly, I don't like the solution, but didn't find anything better so far :(

Comment: thanks @kekert ! I'm going to look into this. Using the player names as a list definitely presents a potential processing speed problem once there are thousands of data points.

Comment: another added complication, if there are multiple threshold groups instead of just one. How to move a person out of one and into another? I'm going to update my question with that.

Comment: @AVD the lists are there because expanding functions (like cumsum) do not work with objects.